# Upgrading and Application from Android 1.6 to Android 2.2 does not work

Tags: android, upgrade, android-2.2-froyo, android-1.6-donut

I currently found out, that my Application developed for Android 1.6 does not work on Android 2.2. I'm quite puzzled about this, because its a very simple Application which almost does nothing.

The Expeption I get is like that:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application [packagename].AndApp:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [packagename].AndApp in loader
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app-private/[packagename]-1.apk]
```

The weirdest part is, that the Class it is searching for here does not exist and never has...

The app itself does nothing than show some text in a textview.

In Android 1.6 I dont get this problem and I cant see a reason, it event works in 2.1.

Has anybody a clue what this problem might be?

The Manifest looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="[packagename]" android:versionName="1.02" android:versionCode="3">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/stop_48"
        android:description="@string/Description" android:name="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".DefaultActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="4"</uses-sdk>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your manifest file. You have not closed the  tag. Please add  before  to close the tag. Then, you will not need the empty class.

Comment: Strange: because its the generated manifest-file and I didn't have this problem with Android 1.6: but closing the application-tag is the answer I was looking for! Thx

Answer (score 0):

after another day struggling with this problem and trying out alot of weird stuff, I came up with the Idea of just simply creating this class it was searching for.

At first it didnt work either, but then I derived this empty class of Application and this seemed to be the solution.

I'm not shure why and I dont know what caused this problem: maybe its a bug in the plugin for Eclipse?

I'm still not satisfied with this result: I would really like to know whats going on here!

If anybody has an explanation for that, pls post.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I've fixed as you said.

I've create the class:

```
public class AndApp extends Application{}
```

And now it works but i don't know why